# How to prove the weak convergence of probability measure on a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(S, d)$ be a metrirc space, $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of probability measure on $S$. If, for every subsequence $\{P_{n'}\}$ of  $\{P_n\}$, there
exists a subsequence $\{P_{n'_k}\}\subset \{P_{n'}\}$ such that it weakly converges to the same probability measure $P$  on $S$, then $\{P_n\}$ weakly converges to $P$.
I wonder how to prove this result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(P_n)$ doesn't converges weakly to $P$. Then, there is a continuous and bounded function $f$ and $\varepsilon >0$ s.t. for all $m\in \mathbb N$ there is $n_m\geq m$ s.t. $$\left|\int_S f\,\mathrm d P_{n_m}-\int_S f\,\mathrm d P\right|\geq \varepsilon .$$

In particular, there are no subsequence of $(P_{n_m})$ that converges weakly to $P$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the whole sequence does not converge to the prescribed limit. Then, either there exists a subsequence, which converges to a limit other than $P$ or there exists a non-converging subsequence. The first case is impossible, since this subsequence will (by assumption) possess a further subsequence with limit $P$. Hence, there is a subsequence, which is not convergent, say $P_{n_k}, k \geq 1$. Note that weak convergence of probability measures may be metrized by a metric $d$ (e.g. by Prokhorov metric). Hence, we have $d(P_{{n_k}_l},P) \geq \epsilon$ for a further subsequence indexed by $l$ for a suitable $\epsilon > 0$. But this sequence, by assumption, possesses a further subsequence $P_{{{n_k}_l}_j}$, indexed by $j$, which converges to $P$ w.r.t. $P$, which is impossible. We have reached a contradiction and the proof follows.